# python pure adb error: read-only file system. Xiaomi

Tags: python, adb

```
from ppadb.client import Client
from ppadb.client import *
import os
client = Client(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
device = client.device("3147da30")
directory = os.fsencode('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\zxczxc')
for i in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(i)
    if filename.endswith(".mp4"):
        i = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\zxczxc\\' + filename)
        device.push(i, "\\sdcard\\DCIM\\Camera")
```

Error:

```
Error:  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/adb python project/app.py", line 12, in <module>
    device.push(i, "\\sdcard\\DCIM\\Camera")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ppadb\device.py", line 61, in push
    self._push(src, dest, mode, progress)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ppadb\device.py", line 55, in _push
    sync.push(src, dest, mode, progress)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ppadb\sync\__init__.py", line 64, in push
    self.connection._check_status()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ppadb\connection.py", line 90, in _check_status     
    raise RuntimeError("ERROR: {} {}".format(repr(recv), error))
RuntimeError: ERROR: 'FAIL' +couldn't create file: Read-only file system
```

Comment: Your question contains only code and the error message. Please also add a text that describes what you are trying to do. BTW: On Android/Linux you should use `/` as path separator, not `\ ` respectively `\\ `.

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing

```
device.push(i, "\\sdcard\\DCIM\\Camera")
```

to:

```
device.push(i, "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera")
```

Android uses `/` as a directory/file separator, *not* `\`.